# Powershell how to pass parameter with special characters

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to pass a variable to powershell script as parameter. Variable has some special characters and the call to ps1 script fails.

Here I just created a sample to show the problem.

```
PS C:\>$pass1 = '?q$*9-W$wcx)O.Ra)X-&6'

PS C:\>powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command 'echo '$pass1''
```

ERROR:

```
At line:1 char:26
+ echo  ?q$*9s8ubhD8c-W$wcx)O.Ra9)DX-D&6
+                          ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:32
+ echo  ?q$*9s8ubhD8c-W$wcx)O.Ra9)DX-D&6
+                                ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:37
+ echo  ?q$*9s8ubhD8c-W$wcx)O.Ra9)DX-D&6
+                                     ~
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation
marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1h40.png)

Comment: Codes and logs should not be attached as images. It is recommended to edit it in text format. See the link below.[how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  /  [do-not-upload-images-of-code-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Update(SOLVED): It was problem with gitlab, in the .gitlab-ci.yaml to translate powershell parameters correct either we need to add them to variables section or use $env: infront of the variable.

[Ref1](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/) and [Ref2](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/1309)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script has a syntax error, it doesn't appear to be a problem with the actual value of the parameter/variable.

This is the line that has a syntax error:

```powershell
powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command 'echo '$pass1''
```

This is where your problem is:

```powershell
'echo '$pass1''
```

You're actually passing 3 things here...

1. `'echo '`
2. `$pass1`
3. `''`

The second single quote is exiting the string.

You need to alternate between single and double strings depending on how you need to use them:

```powershell
$pass1 = '?q$*9-W$wcx)O.Ra)X-&6'
powershell -Command "echo '$pass1'"
```

Comment: Thanks Chad Baldwin, as you suggested I changed it to alternate double quote and single quotes. But now $w disappears inside the powershell script. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Try swapping your single and double quotes. In powershell, single and double quotes act differently. Double quotes mean any variables get replaced with the value of the variable, single quotes just pass it literally. So if you have `$w = 'asdf'; "$w"`, then `'asdf'` is what gets passed. But if you have `$w = 'asdf'; "$w"`, then `'$w'` is what gets passed.

Comment: Some how this is not translating correct when it executes on gitlab windows runner.

here's my power shell script.


-------------------------------------------------------test.ps1---- start ----------------------
Param
(
 [String] $passcode
)

## take backup
## remoteServer, deployToFolder, backupFolder, AppPoolName

write-output "------------------------------------"
write-output "passcode    - $passcode"
write-output "------------------------------------"

$passcode
------------------------------------------------------- end -----------------

Comment: This is how It is called.

PS C:\>powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "./test.ps1 -passcode '$pass1'"

value of $pass1 = ''8c-W$wcx)O'

output shows 

------------------------------------
passcode                         - 8c-W)O
------------------------------------
8c-W)O

Comment: tried to escape by adding ` infront of $wcx .. but has no effect

Comment: @SureshK Try escaping the `$` by doubling it, so `$$wcx`. I've read for escaping exclamation marks you need to put one or two caret `^` characters in front (`^^!`). Maybe other characters need excaping too but that info is hard to find...